# Can't seem to get any links to print using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Hey i'm new to coding with modules and i'm trying to write a program that lists all the new anime episodes that have come out from a website just for some fun(nerdy i know). However I can't seem to be able to print of the links for the episodes and i'm not sure what is wrong. Could someone enlighten me please?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def spider():
    url = 'https://kissanime.to/AnimeList/LatestUpdate'
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
    for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'listing'}):
        href = link.get('href')
        print(href)
spider()
```

Comment: Please be more specific: is it not printing anything, or the wrong things, or...?  What are you expecting, and why (i.e. what is in the HTML you are scraping)?

Comment: Sorry. Yes nothing is being printed but i'm trying to print a list of links that go to recently uploaded episodes from an anime website. Here's some of the HTML i'm scraping.<table class="listing">
    <tbody><tr class="head">
        <th width="70%">
            Anime name
        </th>
        <th width="30%">
            Latest episode
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 10px">
    </tr>
    
    <tr class="odd">
        
        <td>       
            <a href="/Anime/Kaitou-Joker-3rd-Season">
                Kaitou Joker 3rd Season</a>

Comment: There is no `a` tag with a `class` attribute, much less one with a class of `listing`.  There is a `table` tag with such an attribute, though.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've managed to find out that the problem wasn't my code but that when you access this page there is a loading page that appears for 5 seconds before you get on the page you want. My code was scraping this page instead of the one I wanted so that's why nothing came up. However i'm not sure exactly how i'll be able to get around this problem

Answer (score 0):

As you have seem there is up to five seconds to wait so you cannot parse the source with requests, what you get back is what you see when you are in the loading phase in your browser. You could do a get to  `https://kissanime.to/cdn-cgi/l/chk_jschl/cdn-cgi/l/chk_jschl` passing *jschl_vc* and *pass* from teh form but a third param  needed is `jschl-answer` which is calculated using a js function so I don't see a way to get that value:

```
  <form id="challenge-form" action="/cdn-cgi/l/chk_jschl" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="jschl_vc" value="7d830410394a469c1b9afc24326aa5dd"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="pass" value="1466454867.055-eUN53b1Q/B"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="jschl-answer" name="jschl_answer"/>
  </form>
```

You will need something like [*selenium*](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) if you want to parse the site, you can combine it with [*phantomjs*](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) for headless browsing:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


def wait(dr, x):
    element = WebDriverWait(dr, 20).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, x))
    )
    return element

dr = webdriver.PhantomJS()
dr.get("https://kissanime.to/AnimeList/LatestUpdate")

# wait until the table is visible
table = wait(dr, "//table[@class='listing']")
print(table)
```

To get all the links:

```
dr = webdriver.PhantomJS()
dr.get("https://kissanime.to/AnimeList/LatestUpdate")

table_links = wait(dr, "//table[@class='listing']//a")
for link in table_links:
    print(link.get_attribute("href"))
```

Which would give you:

```
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Hundred
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Hundred/Episode-012?id=126873
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Seisen-Cerberus-Ryuukoku-no-Fatalites
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Seisen-Cerberus-Ryuukoku-no-Fatalites/Episode-012?id=126872
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Wagamama-High-Spec
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Wagamama-High-Spec/Episode-011?id=126871
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Usakame
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Usakame/Episode-011?id=126870
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Bakuon
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Bakuon/Episode-012?id=126869
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Pretty-Guardian-Sailor-Moon-Crystal-Death-Busters
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Pretty-Guardian-Sailor-Moon-Crystal-Death-Busters/Episode-038?id=126868
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Kaitou-Joker-3rd-Season
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Kaitou-Joker-3rd-Season/Episode-038?id=126867
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Aoyama-Goushou-Tanpenshuu
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Yu-Gi-Oh-Arc-V-5
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Yu-Gi-Oh-Arc-V-5/Episode-110?id=126859
https://kissanime.to/Anime/New-Dream-Hunter-Rem-Yume-no-Kishitachi
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Dream-Hunter-Rem
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Seitokai-Yakuindomo-OVA-2
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Seitokai-Yakuindomo-OVA-2/Episode-018?id=126853
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Sansha-Sanyou-Dub
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Sansha-Sanyou-Dub/Episode-006?id=126852
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Macross-Delta
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Macross-Delta/Episode-012?id=126851
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Tanaka-kun-wa-Kyou-mo-Kedaruge
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Tanaka-kun-wa-Kyou-mo-Kedaruge/Episode-027?id=126850
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Kare-Baka-Wagahai-no-Kare-wa-Baka-de-R
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Re-Zero-kara-Hajimeru-Isekai-Seikatsu
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Re-Zero-kara-Hajimeru-Isekai-Seikatsu/Episode-012?id=126848
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Kuma-Miko-Girl-meets-Bear
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Sansha-Sanyou
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Sansha-Sanyou/Episode-011?id=126846
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Tonkatsu-DJ-Agetarou
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Tonkatsu-DJ-Agetarou/Episode-011?id=126845
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Nijiiro-Days
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Nijiiro-Days/Episode-023?id=126844
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Pan-de-Peace
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Pan-de-Peace/Episode-012?id=126843
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Mobile-Suit-Gundam-Iron-Blooded-Orphans-Dub
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Mobile-Suit-Gundam-Iron-Blooded-Orphans-Dub/Episode-003?id=126842
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Hunter-x-Hunter-2011-Dub
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Hunter-x-Hunter-2011-Dub/Episode-009?id=126841
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Momokuri-1
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Momokuri-1/Episode-010?id=126840
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Boku-no-Hero-Academia-My-Hero-Academia
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Boku-no-Hero-Academia-My-Hero-Academia/Episode-012?id=126839
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Dragon-Ball-Super
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Dragon-Ball-Super/Episode-048?id=126838
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Monster-Strike
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Monster-Strike/Episode-028?id=126837
https://kissanime.to/Anime/One-Piece
https://kissanime.to/Anime/One-Piece/Episode-746?id=126836
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Cardfight-Vanguard-G-Stride-Gate-hen
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Cardfight-Vanguard-G-Stride-Gate-hen/Episode-036?id=126835
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Folktales-from-Japan
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Folktales-from-Japan/Episode-219?id=126831
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Cardfight-Vanguard-G-Stride-Gate-hen-Dub
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Cardfight-Vanguard-G-Stride-Gate-hen-Dub/Episode-029?id=126834
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Mobile-Suit-Gundam-More-Information-on-the-Universal-Century
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Endride-Dub
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Endride-Dub/Episode-006?id=126822
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Pokemon-XY-Z-Dub
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Pokemon-XY-Z-Dub/Episode-018?id=126821
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Mahoutsukai-Precure
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Mahoutsukai-Precure/Episode-019?id=126747
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Aikatsu-Stars
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Aikatsu-Stars/Episode-011?id=126820
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Haifuri
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Haifuri/Episode-011?id=126818
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Kiznaiver
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Kiznaiver/Episode-011?id=126817
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Ragnastrike-Angels
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Gakusen-Toshi-Asterisk-2nd-Season
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Tanaka-kun-wa-Itsumo-Kedaruge
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Tanaka-kun-wa-Itsumo-Kedaruge/Episode-011?id=126815
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Kyoukai-no-Rinne-TV-2nd-Season-RIN-NE
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Kyoukai-no-Rinne-TV-2nd-Season-RIN-NE/Episode-036?id=126812
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Gyakuten-Saiban-Sono-Shinjitsu-Igi-Ari
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Gyakuten-Saiban-Sono-Shinjitsu-Igi-Ari/Episode-012?id=126813
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Sakamoto-desu-ga
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Sakamoto-desu-ga/Episode-010?id=126811
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Shounen-Maid-Dub
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Shounen-Maid-Dub/Episode-005?id=126810
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Mayoiga
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Shounen-Maid
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Shounen-Maid/Episode-010?id=126806
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Future-Card-Buddyfight-DDD
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Future-Card-Buddyfight-DDD/Episode-012?id=126807
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Bonobono-2016
https://kissanime.to/Anime/Bonobono-2016/Episode-011?id=126805
```

If you prefer using bs4 to do the parsing, you can pass the source over after waiting:

```
from urlparse import urljoin

dr = webdriver.PhantomJS()
dr.get("https://kissanime.to/AnimeList/LatestUpdate")

wait(dr, "//table[@class='listing']//a")
soup = BeautifulSoup(dr.page_source)
for link in soup.select("table.listing a"):
    print(urljoin("https://kissanime.to" ,link["href"]))
```